# In Python - Trying to aggregate a row and create a pivot table

Tags: python

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Custodian'])

del df['Name']
del df['Model 2']

print(df)
```

Shows this:

```
                            Model  Current Value
Custodian                                       
Heldaway                 529 Plan        3791.94
Heldaway                 529 Plan       11364.87
Heldaway                 529 Plan       22422.58
Heldaway                 529 Plan       33859.74
Heldaway   Core Aggressive Growth      667703.89
                          ...            ...
US Bank           High Yield Cash           0.00
US Bank           High Yield Cash       60056.55
US Bank           High Yield Cash       18023.68
US Bank           High Yield Cash           0.00
US Bank           High Yield Cash      142132.76

[5286 rows x 2 columns]
```

I would like to make it so it custodian type shows once then all the models under that custodian. Then I would like to know how to make it so the model column is sorted by a specific order according to the string.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean:

```py
df=df.reset_index().groupby(["Model", "Custodian"], as_index=False)["Current Value"].sum()
```

Comment: @nicktrajan - please write these points in your question, in a way that somebody who doesn't know your dataset could understand it. I understand you need to group based on certain transformation of your columns - please be explicit what this transformation should be and also what exactly is your desired output. Also - show what *You* did so far - SO is not a free coding services, we can help and *not* do it for you.